Elongate - Word usage
Person 1 - I never cry for more than a few minutes.
Person 2 - You should elongate your crying. Crying for a long period helps release endorphins.
Is the first sentence used by person 2 grammatically accurate? Is the use of elongate grammatically correct? I've noticed people on the internet, claiming "elongate" is reserved for physical objects. However, I've also found an example on the Huffington Post where we're using the word with regard to time: "This is far better than expecting an employee to juggle multiple work assignments at once, elongating the time it takes to complete any of them in a satisfactory manner."

In some ways, it's nitpicking, but it's worth pointing out that this is not about "grammatical correctness"; it's a verb, and it's being used as a verb; that much is correct. It's just that "people don't use it that way": i.e., it's "not idiomatic."

We usually use elongate to mean make something physically longer, like if I were knitting a scarf that had reached 150 cm and I added more to make it 190 cm long. We don’t usually use elongate about durations (time), but only about spatial extent.

Even with a more natural verb, such as extend, lengthen, stretch out, prolong,... I don't think it's idiomatic to refer to your crying as a the object of such a verb (metaphorically equating increased linear measure to increased duration). Much more natural to just say "You should cry for longer"

I wouldn't use elongate there, but some people might.
It is likely the case that we most often use elongate to mean physically lengthen, as the following examples show:

...elongates the spine
...elongated the often short athletes' legs.

Cambridge Dictionary
One (arguably) non-physical common use describes stretching out a sound, as in, pronouncing a word more slowly:

By elongating vowels and stressing transitions more clearly...
It's as though he sings it, elongating the words and phrases with his musical voice.

Ibid
All of these example sound perfectly natural to me.  However, you can find more than a few examples that are quite close to elongate crying, which, to me sound unnatural:

It could elongate to three and half hours, but that's not enough to spoil your weekend.
...a meal elongates the meeting.
So we are elongating our games...
...hostage-taking and barricading elongates the duration of the raid.

Ibid
If someone's OK with "elongate our games", "elongates our meeting", or "elongates the duration", it wouldn't be a stretch to imagine them being OK with "elongate your crying".

But if I don't like the use of elongate there, what would I say?  Probably prolong.
Here are some examples that seem to fit the pattern of prolong crying:

...prolonged their agony.
prolongs the feeling of being stuck
it's not prolonging the pain...

NB: I can find virtually no good examples of "prolong your crying".  There are some examples of "prolong crying" as in "such and such condition can prolong crying in infants," but that's possibly a somewhat different use.

Solid answer with good examples. As far as alternatives go, I probably would say simply, "You should keep crying" (where keep is used here as a synonym for continue)—but if I had to retain the your, I'd probably use continue.
